# using custom properties in Nifi

Tags: properties, apache-nifi

How would I use one custom property within another in Nifi?
Please note that am using custom property file.

Eg: I have the following in the custom property file.

```
prop_1=/path/to/dir1
prop_2=/path/to/dir2
prop_3=${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file1
prop_4=${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file2
```

Now, within nifi processor, where expression language is supported, when I give

`${prop_3}` or `${prop_4}`

I get error `${prop_1}` is not a file or directory.

But if I provide the value as `${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file1`, it works.

What is the problem when I give `${prop_3}`?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4):

Properties file is loaded as a map of key-value constants. No evaluations are done during this load.

You defined `prop_3=${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file1`. This means, that `prop_3` equals to literal value `${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file1` (N.B.: no evaluations).

So, in attribute (that supports expression language) you set: `${prop_3}`. And NiFi evaluated the `${prop_3}` expression to literal value `${prop_1}/${prop_2}/file1` (again, without repeated evaluation).

Comment: Thanks @dagget. Got it. I was assuming that evaluation of these properties happen during load.

Answer (score 0):

As daggett noted, the property values are loaded from the custom properties file in a single operation, and cannot reference each other during that load process. However, you can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor before the processor which is doing this evaluation, and use a dynamic property (click the `+` button on the top right of the properties table) to assign `prop3 = /${prop1}/${prop2}/file1` and then reference `${prop3}` in any following processors.

Comment: it could be good to be able to plug a custom VariableRegistry to nifi.

Comment: I would suggest you open a Jira for that. There is active work on all the registries, and community guidance and real world use cases are highly valued. In conjunction, the code is open source, so if someone contributes a stable and resilient implementation/improvement, I have confidence it would be thoroughly reviewed and integrated with thanks.

Comment: Thanks @daggett and Andy for your inputs.

Comment: how can we read integer values from property file using ${batchSize}. we are getting 'not a valid integer exception'